# PayPal IPN Delivery Status set to Disabled

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We are a 3rd party online marketplace. We connect buyers and sellers. Our IPN notify_url has been running for years with no problems. One of our sellers has been receiving PayPal payments from a buyer for their goods but we have not been receiving the IPN callbacks.

We asked the seller to check their IPN history and it is showing that the callbacks to our notify_url are Delivery Status= Disabled.

The sellers PayPal account is OK
Our notify_url is OK

I realise there is the IPN Settings page at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify-edit where a hardcoded URL can be set and IPN messages can be switched to ON.... but our notify_url is fed via the form data at checkout. This option is set set OFF by default and we have tens of thousands of users still receiving IPN callbacks ok to our notify_url with the default setting && POSTed notify_url so the problem won't be there.

Any idea why they are disabled and how to get them re-enabled for this seller.

Answer (score 6):

IPN function can be disabled due to below reasons:
1. PayPal failed to send IPN message to this merchant's IPN URL, after 100 times failure, IPN function is disabled by PayPal.
2. Merchant disable IPN function manually.
Merchant can enable IPN function in https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify-edit .

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who found very useful this reply I just want to add: do not waste hours trying to figure out how to locate that page in the new paypal's interface.

I've asked to PP support how to locate it and they just told me to type the following link in the nav bar.
https://www.paypal.com/it/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES

You actually have to save the url to your library in order to get back.